# RestKit and iCloud directory backup policies

Tags: ios5, restkit, icloud

I am working on an IOS 5.0+ project that uses the latest RestKit to download, map and persist core data. I am looking for a definitive answer on Apple's iCloud storage guidelines with RestKit. Do I need to take any extra steps to make sure the data downloaded for use in the app is not automatically backed up to an iCloud account.Do I need to alter the default location for the directories used. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your Core Data store is not saved in an ubiquity container (See: [URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) it will never be synced.

Also in the [Using iCloud in Conjunction with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html) section of the documentation they state:

> Setting up your Core Data store to handle iCloud requires only a
>   little extra effort on your part. The steps you must follow depend on
>   whether you are using a single Core Data store as a central library
>   for your app or whether you are creating separate stores for
>   individual documents.

You have to do some explicit changes for synchronization. If you read the documents further,  they mention some keys like `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey`. If you search for this in the RestKit source, you will not find it - this is because RestKit does not sync with iCloud automatically (and they can not because iCloud is an app level synchronization framework).

Answer (score 0):

Our app was just rejected for storing our database in the Documents folder. The seed file or app content in the database has got 3.3MB. We also store user created content in the database of course. The official statement is: **2.23 Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected**

So now we are checking out on [Technical Q&A QA1719](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342) to prevent the database from being synced to iCloud.